# append/populating values in combobox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select

Append the options into another combobox, when user select the value from the first combobox. Need help..!!

```
 <select id="design" onmouseup="showOfficer()" >
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
 </select>

<select id="officers" class="officers" multiple="multiple"><div id="show_officer"></div></select>
```

**AJAX Code**

```
<script language="javascript" >
function showOfficer(){
                        document.getElementById("msg4").style.display="block";
                       $.ajax({
                            url: '../service/list_assign_officer.jsp',
                            data: 'design_id='+ $('#design').val(),
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(msg){document.getElementById("show_officer").innerHTML=msg;
                                document.getElementById("msg4").style.display="none";
                            }});
                    }
</script>
```

code of **list_assign_officer.jsp**

```
<%@include file="../dbconfig.jsp" %><%
String design=request.getParameter("design_id");
 String buffer="";
 try{
     int count=0;
 ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("SELECT OFFICER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME FROM OFFICER WHERE STATUS_TYPE='UNASSIGN' AND DESIGN_ID='"+design+"'");//
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(1)+"</option>";
   count++;
   }
 if(count==0)
     {
  buffer=buffer+"<option value='ERROR'>OFFICERS ASSIGNED ALREADY</option>";
 }
 }
 catch(Exception e){
    buffer=buffer+"<option value='ERROR'>OFFICERS ASSIGNED ALREADY</option>"+e;
 }
 buffer=buffer+"";
 //out.print(buffer);
 response.getWriter().print(buffer);
 %>
```

Comment: try to debug it step by step. try to fire a simple ajax request that returns a string to be sure that JS and AJAX are running smoothly.and take it one step at a time. A suggestion : for id="design" use onchage() event , and also use jqery $.post method directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code:

```
<select id="design" onChange="showOfficer()" >
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>
 <option value="D">D</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<div id="msg4"></div>


<script language="javascript" >
function showOfficer(){
    alert('function is getting');
                        document.getElementById("msg4").style.display="block";
                       $.ajax({
                            url: '../service/list_assign_officer.jsp',
                            data: 'design_id='+ $('#design').val(),
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(msg){document.getElementById("show_officer").innerHTML=msg;
                                document.getElementById("msg4").style.display="none";
                            }});
                    }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YvyWc/18/

Comment: my code is also working fine.. but, the problem is when it's getting the value from the requested page, then it's unable to append into the combobox. that's my problem

Comment: Check if you need to rebuild the combobox after you are finished appending additional options.

Comment: please help me.. it's not appending.

Comment: it will append after selected dropdown.This is will help you http://jsfiddle.net/YvyWc/25/

Comment: and was flagged today. I'm dumb. I'm cleaning the site.